# Extensible application markup language

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is Extensible application markup language{ xaml } userdefined or predefined language?

Comment: What is an userdefined or predefined language anyway? Even google doesn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

XAML is a pre-defined XML-based markup language developed by Microsoft.